# Connect Sprint boot application with dynamic databases

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

my project has a requirement to create a database for each registered user on the platform. **Each user will have their sub-domain, and each sub-domain will have a dedicated database with common schema.** Application is using Spring boot. What is the best way to connect to dynamic database, as single jar file will be responsible to respond all the requests coming from different sub-domains.

*Yes, we will think about load-balancing, but this question is not about that.* This is to create a centralised spring boot application to talk to each sub-domain with different databases.

Help/suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could consider using a RoutingDataSource to get (or connect and get) the correct datasource based on the user.
Example guide: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-abstract-routing-data-source